# How to get integrated camera on macbook pro working

Tags: macbook, camera

I'm loving elementary on my macbook pro (manufactured 2017 I believe). Anyone know how to get the integrated camera working so I can use cheese and other video conferencing functions?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install AppleUSBVideoSupport to Elementary 5.1 (Hara) to get my camera to work on an older 2007 MacBook (2,1).  Your MacBook is much newer and can only assume it's the same issue.

This post outlines the steps.  There is a "isight-firmware-tools" package to install but before you do that, you have to grab (or download) the support file outlined in this article:

https://turanct.wordpress.com/tag/appleusbvideosupport/

NOTE: as of March 6th, in the event you want to use the iSight in Chrome, I am [still working with the Chromium team to recognize the built-in iSight](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1056070#c4).  In Elementary, the default Camera app works and so does Zoom conference software.

Comment: Same MacBook same problem (Ubuntu 20, Mint 20). Chromium devs have closed this issue because they are unable to reproduce it. :( I guess i will have to throw the Macbook into trash instead of giving it to local school for kids without PC, because it will be unusable to them. School uses MS Teams (Electron app) for conferences.

Answer (score 0):

Following these instructions I got my integrated cam to work. EOS Hera on MacBook Air 2013. Hope it helps.
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/91429169-add-the-drivers-for-a-mac-book-facetimehd-camera